# Grid Star-Size in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid

I have a grid as follows,

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

How do I give the `Height = "0.5*"` in code behind?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can use:

```
rowDefinition.Height = new GridLength(0.5, GridUnitType.Star);
```

Answer (score 21):

```
grid.RowDefinitions[0].Height = new GridLength(0.5, GridUnitType.Star);
```