# Applying Grid Star Size in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I construct this piece of XAML programatically?

```
<Grid Name="gridMarkets">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="16" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 </Grid>
```

Is it any elegant solution for parse and construct controls dynamically?

I was trying to do something:

```
RowDefinition newRow = new RowDefinition();
newRow.Height = new GridLength(10);
newGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(newRow);
```

But how do I assign a `*` sign?

Looking for any kind of ideas to this problem!
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grid Star-Size in code behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459595/grid-star-size-in-code-behind)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use the `Grid.Star` unit type

```
newRow.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
```

You can also use the [XamlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx) object to convert XAML strings into UI objects from code-behind, although I usually prefer to manually create objects like how you are creating them.

Comment: Thanks! But why its 1? not a Zero?

Comment: If you want one star, then you need to specify you want one star, not zero. If you didn't know, you can use more than one star in XAML too: e.g. `Height="2*"`.

Comment: @WildGoat The default unit is when you use `Height="*"` is 1. This means the row will take up an equal amount of space with all other star-sized rows. For example, if you had 2 rows that both had `Height="*"`, both rows would take up an equal amount of space. If first row had `Height="2*"`, then it would be twice the size of the 2nd row. If Row1 had `Height="2*"` and Row2 had `Height="3*"`, then the 1st row would take up 2/5 of the available space and the 2nd row would take up 3/5.

Answer (score 9):

Here are some examples:

```
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition {Height = new GridLength(10)});
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition {Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star), MinHeight = 16});

grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition {Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)});
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition {Height = GridLength.Auto});
```

and similarly for columns.

Answer (score 7):

Using the `GridLength` constructor that allows you to specify `GridUnitType` is the right approach here, as others suggested.

But if, for some reason, you want to actually convert the string value to the correct type the same way it's done in XAML, you can do that too:

Look at the `GridLength` type: it has defined the `TypeConverter` attribute with the parameter `typeof(GridLengthConverter)`. This means you can use that type to perform the conversion:

```
new GridLengthConverter().ConvertFromString("*")
```