# How to set WPF component height to "*" in code?

Tags: wpf, height, code-behind

I want to set a component height to `"*"` dynamically in code. How can I do that?

I know how to set it to a defined value:

```
DataGrid.Height = "500";
```

And how to set to "Auto":

```
DataGrid.Height = Double.NaN;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Star sizing only exists for very few components, the `Grid` itself is *not* one of them. [`GridLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridlength.aspx) has [a constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557307.aspx) which takes the type of the sizing sheme as parameter.

If you want a component to stretch do not set any value for `Width`/`Height` and make sure the `Horizontal`/`VerticalAlignment` is `Stretch`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using the columndefinitions/rowdefinitions with `GridUnitType`, for example :

```
RowDefinition rd = new RowDefinition();
rd.Height = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Star);
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(rd);
```

See also : [Grid Star-Size in code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459595/grid-star-size-in-code-behind)